# Java cannot find symbol for loops, logic problems?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, loops

Ok, my program in this specific section takes a line of data from a studentAnswer string array, the value of which would be something like `TTFFTFTFTF`. I am supposed to take this, and compare it against a key array, which might look like `TFFFTFTFTF`. A student takes a quiz, and my program calculates the points correct.

My intention is to use a separate points array to find the numeric grade for the student. The index of `studentAnswer` refers to a specific student. So `studentAnswer[i]` is `TTFFTFTFTF`. I use substrings to compare each individual T/F against the correct answer in `key[]`, which would have a single T/F in each index. Then, if they are correct in their answer, I add a 1 to the correlating index in `points[]` and will later find the sum of `points[]` to find the numeric grade out of ten.

My problem here is that String `origAns`, used to define the student's original answer string, is getting a Java Error cannot find Symbol. I have tried placing the instantiation of `origAns` within each different for loop, but I can't get the program to work. Int `i` is meant to follow each specific student- I have four parallel arrays that will all log the student's ID number, numeric grade, letter grade, and original answers. So that is the intention of `i`, to go through each student. Then `j` should be used to go through each of these original student answer strings and compare it to the correct answer...
Logically, it makes sense to me where I would put it, but java doesn't agree. Please help me to understand this error!

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswer.length; i++){
    String origAns = studentAnswer[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < key.length; j++){
        if (origAns.substring[j] == key[j]){
            //substring of index checked against same index of key
            points[j] = 1;
        }
        if (origAns.substring[j] != key[j]){
            points[j] = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: the comparison `origAns.substring[j] == key[j]` compares only the references ... you need to use `key[j].equals(origAns.substring[j])`

Comment: and it should be `origAns.substring(j)` ... `()` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to call the `substring` *method* - but you're trying to access it as if it were a field. So first change would be:

```
if (origAns.substring(j) == key[j])
```

Except that will be comparing string *references* instead of *contents*, so you might want:

```
if (origAns.substring(j).equals(key[j]))
```

Actually, I suspect you want `charAt` to get a single character - `substring` will return you a string with everything after the specified index:

```
if (origAns.charAt(j) == key[j])
```

... where `key` would be a `char[]` here.

You can also avoid doing the "opposite" comparison by using an `else` clause instead.

You should also indent your code more carefully, for readability. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswer.length; i++) {
    String origAns = studentAnswer[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
        if (origAns.charAt(j) == key[j]) {
           points[j] = 1;
        } else {
           points[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And now, you can change that to use a *conditional* expression instead of an if/else:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswer.length; i++) {
    String origAns = studentAnswer[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
        points[j] = origAns.charAt(j) == key[j] ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very thorough, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method in Java, you use parentheses `()` instead of brackets `[]`.

Since `substring` is a method, you should call it like so

```
if (origAns.substring(j) == key[j])
```

A few other notes, you should use the `equals` method for comparisons (*especially* those comparisons involving `String`s.)

```
if (origAns.substring(j).equals(key[j]))
```

Also, you should use `charAt` to extract a single character at some position in a string.  `substring(j)` will return a string of characters starting at position `j`.

```
if (origAns.charAt(j).equals(key[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is very long and I have not read it from the beginning to end. But I can see at least one problem in your code:

`if (origAns.substring[j] == key[j])`

You are comparing strings using `==` instead of using method `equals()`:

`if (origAns.substring[j].equals(key[j]))`

Answer (score 0):

Substring is a function, not a member, of String objects. Check out the example at the top of this page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Notice the use of parenthesis instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a String use charAt function

```
String studentAnswer = "TTFFTFTFTF";
for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswer.length(); i++)
{
   char origAns = studentAnswer.charAt(i);
        }
```

Else if you are using an char array then

```
char studentAnswer[] = "TTFFTFTFTF".toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswer.length; i++){
            char origAns = studentAnswer[i];
        }
```